# "Row not found or changed" when updating value of single attribute, but only for SOME rows

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Okay I will try to make this pretty brief. I have done a lot of searching the last 1-2 days and I can't find an answer to my problem so I will try to narrow it down. The most common cause of "row not found or changed" in LINQ/SQL appears to be a schema discrepancy between the database and the .dbml file (based on both my research and my personal experience). The database I'm working with is too complex for it to be worth sharing the full schema, so I just want to ask one main "hypothetical" question:

**If the "Row not found or changed" error only occurs for SOME rows, despite them all having the exact same operation done on them, is it still possible that it could be an issue with .dbml discrepancies (nullable/non-nullable, data types being wrong, etc)?**

I feel like if there was a normal schema issue in the .dbml file, it wouldn't let me update ANY rows in the table, but in this case it lets me update most of them without an error.

My guess right now, which I am about to investigate, is that it may be failing when the row is connected to another table via a foreign key and **that** table has an issue in the .dbml, but I wanted to post this question now because I have put a lot of hours into this issue and would like to resolve it pretty soon, so maybe there is a stupid reason that I'm unaware of.

Thanks for any help. I shouldn't really need help with this because it's kinda stupid, but I'm really frustrated

Comment: One cause could be a lack of primary key when using a existing SQL view for example

Comment: I think that you problem is that you update the same row on different context or directly on data base after you get it from the database to your current context. try to debug and compare the row against what you on database before you change it.